# ArrayAdapter in an onClickListner is not working

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

What I am trying to do here is to display a list of strings using `ArrayList<String>` and `ArrayAdapter<String>` when a user clicks a button. I want to declare all the members i.e. **adapter**, **ArrayList** and the **list layout** as **global** because I want to add more buttons later with the same feature of displaying a list of strings.

This code has no error but it's not working. I put the `Toast` in the `onClick` to make sure the `onClick` is working. I can see the toast but not the `listView` I want to see.

**class file**

`R.id.button_news` is the button id. `R.layout.activity_primary_content` is the layout that I'm using in this class `PrimaryContent`

`R.layout.list_view_secondary` is the layout where the listView `R.id.list_view` is located.

`R.layout.list_view_secondary` layout and the `PrimaryContent` class are not related but I want to use the `listView` which is in the `list_view_secondary` layout to display from the `PrimaryContent`.

In this line of code

`arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(view.getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);` I tried by put the context `view.getContext()` and `getBaseContext()` both of them are not working.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PrimaryContent extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final String LOG_TAG = PrimaryContent.class.getSimpleName();

    public ListView listView;
    public ArrayList<String> arrayList;
    public ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_primary_content);

        final LayoutInflater factory = getLayoutInflater();
        final View rootView = factory.inflate(R.layout.list_view_secondary, null);
        listView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_view);

        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {
            arrayList.add("World News");
        }

        Button news = findViewById(R.id.button_news);
        news.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Damn",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                for (String x: arrayList) {
                    Log.v(LOG_TAG,x);
                    System.out.println();
                }
                arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(view.getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayList);
                listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**R.layout.list_view_secondary**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" />
```

Comment: @MikeM. Help me fix this error

Comment: Check if  `activity_primary_content.xml` have `list_view_secondary`

Comment: What's the relationship between ```R.layout.activity_primary_content``` and ```R.layout.list_contain_secondary```? It seems that they have no relationship but where will you display your list?

Comment: Try to cast the result of this line to list view like `listView = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_view_secondary);`.

Comment: @zzh `R.layout.activity_primary_content` and `R.layout.list_contain_secondary` are not related. `R.layout.list_contain_secondary` has a listView `R.id.list_view_secondary`, I want to use that listView to display a list of Strings when a user clicks a button from the `R.layout.activity_primary_content`

Comment: You need a layout to display ```R.id.list_view_secondary```. Put it in ```R.layout.activity_primary_content```.

Comment: @zhh there was a typo in the code can you please check again. I also updated the `list_view_secondary` layout where the `list_view` is located

Comment: Is ```R.layout.list_view_secondary``` included in ```R.layout.activity_primary_content```?

Comment: @zzh `R.layout.list_view_secondary` and  `R.layout.activity_primary_content` are different layout they are not related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add the inflated layout to your parent layout, for example:

```
LinearLayout parentLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
parentLayout.addView(rootView);
```

Comment: there was a typo in the code can you please check again. I also updated the `list_view_secondary` layout where the `list_view is located`

Comment: `I/ListViewIsNull=: false`  it says false

Comment: Try the same under the line: `arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(view.getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayList);` for arrayAdapter

Comment: What, if I have multiple buttons and I want to open the listView layout with some contents (different for every button) instead of adding the `rootView` to the `parentLayout`. How can I do it?

Comment: To open the listView with different content you must use different adapters and set them to the listView. If you don't want the rootView just put the listView inside your activity